# Prove a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are both contractions with contraction constant $\lambda , \mu \in (0,0.5)$. Suppose in addition that both $|f|$ and $|g|$ are bounded by $1$. Prove that $fg$ ($f$ times $g$) is a contraction with respect to the standard metric.

### My attempt

Here is what I know

Since $f$ is a contraction

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \lambda |x-y|$$

Since $g$ is a contraction

$$|g(x)-g(y)| \leq \mu |x-y|$$

Since $|f|$ and $|g|$ are bounded by $1$

$$|f|\leq 1 \\ |g| \leq 1$$

I think that in order to show that $f$ times $g$ is a contraction, we need to show that:

$$|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)| \leq (\lambda)( \mu )(|x-y|)$$

Not sure how to proceed...

After hint(s)

$$|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|= |f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(y)+f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(y) \\ 
|f(x)(g(x)-g(y))+g(y)(f(x)+g(y))|$$

Triangle inequality says: $$|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$$
so the above is

$$\leq |f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|$$

Not sure how this helps

Comment: Try triangular inequality add and subtract f-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a standard argument:
$$|f(x)g(x)-f(y) g(y)| = |f(x)g(x) - f(x) g(y) + f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(y)| \le$$
$$\le |f(x)(g(x)-g(y))| + |g(y)(f(x)-f(y))| \le 1 \cdot \mu |x-y| + 1 \cdot \lambda |x-y| = (\lambda + \mu)|x-y|$$
and $\lambda + \mu \in (0,1)$ is a constant.

Comment: I get it until ... $\leq 1 \cdot \mu |x-y| + 1 \cdot \lambda |x-y| = (\lambda + \mu)|x-y|$

Comment: how is that part true?

Comment: Well use the hypothesis. Firstly $|f(x) (g(x)-g(y))| = |f(x)|\cdot |g(x)-g(y)|$. Then $|f(x)| \le 1$ and $|g(x)-g(y)| \le \mu |x-y|$. SImilarly for the other summand.